# Spring batch: Concept of child steps?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to understand how the concept of spring batch can be applied to our use case.

We will have to read data out of a database and create a fixed length flat file out of it. Specifically the database will look similar to this:

```
|---------|        |---------|
|  Person | 1----n | Address |
|---------|        |---------|
     1
     |
     n
|---------|
|   Job   |
|---------|
```

The output file will look similar to this:

```
PERSON1HEADER
PERSON1INFORMATION
ADDRESS1.1
ADRRESS1.2
JOB1.1
PERSON1FOOTER#OFADDRESS2#OFJOB1
PERSON2HEADER
PERSON2INFORMATION
ADDRESS2.1
JOB2.1
JOB2.2
PERSON2FOOTER#OFADDRESS1#OFJOB2
```

My first idea was to create a job which starts step "Person". The Person step would then load all information from the DB and start for **each** person more steps, e.g. address & job steps.

The idea is to have some kind of parent child connection between steps which I was unable to create within my JavaConfig.

The current idea is to create a custom `LineAggregator` which creates all the lines for each person. I really feel there is suppossed to be a cleaner way to do this. 
POC of my current approach:

```
public class MyLineAggregator implements LineAggregator<Person> {

    private Map<String, LineAggregator<Person>> aggregators;

    @Override
    public String aggregate(Person item) {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

       builder.append(aggregators.get("person").aggregate(item) + LINE_ENDING);
       for(Address address : item.getAddress()) {
           builder.append(aggregators.get("address").aggregate(address) + LINE_ENDING);
       }
       for(Job job : item.getJob()) {
           builder.append(aggregators.get("job").aggregate(job) + LINE_ENDING);
       }

       return builder.toString();
    }

    public void setAggregators(Map<String, LineAggregator<Person>> aggregators) {
        this.aggregators = aggregators;
    }
}
```

Job Config:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> itemWriter3(MyLineAggregator myLineAggregator) {
            return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                    .name("flatfile")
                    .resource(new FileSystemResource("target/test-outputs/output.txt"))
                    .lineAggregator(myLineAggregator)
                    .build();
}

@Bean
public Step testStep(FlatFileItemWriter<Person> itemWriter3) {
    RepositoryItemReader<Person> repoReader = new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
            .repository(personRepo)
            .sorts(Map.of("personId", Sort.Direction.ASC))
            .saveState(false)
            .methodName("findAll").build();

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("testStep")
            .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
            .reader(repoReader)
            .writer(itemWriter3)
            .build();
}
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your PoC looks good to me and I don't think you really need to create parent/child relation between steps. The closest you can get if you want to do that is to use a [FlowStep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/FlowStep.html).

Since your `RepositoryItemReader` already grabs persons with their addresses and jobs, there is no need to do additional queries for each person's details (addresses and jobs) like you would do using the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders). Same for the line aggregator, I would have implemented it in the same way.